# extract file name from html file uploader

Tags: python

I am developing a `python` web app. One of the page has file uploader functionality using html `<input type="file" id="file">`. I want to get the filename of uploaded file by the user. In my backend the function receieve the input box value as `str` for eg `C:\fakepath\hello.txt`. I tried below code to extract filename, suppose user uploaded `hello.txt` file

```
def process(value: str) -> bool:
  status: bool = False
  print(f'{value}')  # gives C:\fakepath\hello.txt
  
  file_path: Path = Path(value)
  file_name: str = file_path.name  # gives C:\fakepath\hello.txt and not hello.txt
  
  # further processing code
  
  return status
```

What I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server is presumably an UNIX box, so `Path` (and `os.path`) assumes UNIX paths and doesn't care about Windows-style separators.

Might be simplest to just

```
name = file_path.rpartition("/" if "/" in file_path else "\\")[-1]
```

to sniff out the separator from the name.

You could also use `pathlib.PosixPath` and `pathlib.WindowsPath` (and `posixpath` and `ntpath` for the modules), but it's probably not worth it.

Comment: Hi AKX, I tried other ways as you suggested like `PurePath`, `PosixPath` but they returning the entire path and not just file name. It seems `str` functions may need to use.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is related your function, everything is correct in final you return your status instead of file name

This is your code, and it will return only whole path because of print(f'{value}'), and False because of "return status"

```
def process(value: str) -> bool:
  status: bool = False
  print(f'{value}')  # gives C:\fakepath\hello.txt
  
  file_path: Path = Path(value)
  file_name: str = file_path.name  # gives C:\fakepath\hello.txt and not hello.txt
  
  # further processing code
  
  return status
```

you just need to change return file_name and it will print out file name correctly

```
def process(value: str) -> bool:
    status: bool = False
    print(f'{value}')  # gives C:\fakepath\hello.txt

    file_name: str = value.rsplit('\\', 1)[-1]  # gets the file name from the right side
    
    # Further processing code (add your processing logic here)
    
    return file_name  # Assuming you want to return the status at the end

print(process(value=r"C:\fakepath\hello.txt"))
```